# Executing remote python script in background over SSH

Tags: python, ssh

I have a python file "run.py" like below on my remote server.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["nohup", "python", "/home/admin/Packet/application.py", "&"])
```

I want to run that file from my local computer using SSH. I'm trying like the below. However, my local terminal got stuck there. It seems it isn't being run in the background.

`ssh -n -f -i /Users/aws/aws.pem admin@hello_world.com 'python /home/admin/run.py'`

After running that command, my terminal got stuck.

Comment: You may wan to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen

Comment: @kfx, no, absolutely unnecessary. The problem is that the process is indeed not being sent to background

Comment: Why is it a python script? Shell would be sufficient and simpler, no?

Comment: @JanHudec, Could you also answer that in shell?

Comment: @moeseth: Don't you need to add ">&" and "/dev/null" after your script and before "&"?

Comment: @moeseth, have you tried simply `nohup python /home/admin/Packet/application.py &`?

Comment: @DavidCullen, please, remember, that it is being started by python subprocess.Popen with a list argument. Therefore **NEITHER** of `&` nor `>&` are special, because list argument is *not* passed through shell.

Comment: @JanHudec, I have. It still hangs.

Comment: What about "ssh -n -f -i /Users/aws/aws.pem admin@hello_world.com 'nohup python /home/admin/Packet/application.py >& /dev/null &'"?

Comment: @DavidCullen, it works. but no idea why i cannot redirect the output to access.log by doing &> /home/admin/access.log &

Comment: @moeseth: Have you tried running "nohup python /home/admin/Packet/application.py >& /home/admin/access.log &" on the target computer?

Comment: @DavidCullen, I have but it doesn't work.

Comment: @moeseth: Why doesn't it work? Maybe you need to run your script without nohup and in the foreground to make sure there are no defects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99971/discussion-between-david-cullen-and-moeseth).

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example I'm using, you can try something like this, customizing the ssh_options.

```
import subprocess
ssh_options = '-o ConnectTimeout=10 -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
server_name = 'remote_server.domain'
cmd = 'ssh ' + ssh_options + ' ' + server_name + ' "/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/python /home/admin/run.py 2>&1 &"'  
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Later you can redirect the output to a flat file, changing :

```
2>&1 &
```

for:

```
>> /path/lo/log_file.txt 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Hey, this works. However, I want to execute script from remote server.

Comment: My setup is a little more complex, but what I'm doing is basically this, the remote cmd download the script and calls the interpreter to execute it  "'/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/wget -T3 -qO- " + args.url + args.script + " | " + args.interpreter + ....